# /etc/synthetic.conf not working in Venture 13.2

Tags: macos-ventura

I used to create a /store directory with a record in /etc/synthetic.conf like:

```
store Users/wnm3/store
```

where the latter is a directory I own in my home directory. Rebooting doesn't seem to create the symlink for /store to /Users/wnm3/store as it used to. Is this a known bug or an issue between the chair and keyboard?

I've worked around using an export for store to the directory in my .zshrc so at least I can use cd store/... (but not cd /store/...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I'd forgotten there needed to be a **tab** character to separate the symlink name (e.g., store) and the actual directory it points to (e.g., Users/wnm3/store). Once I changed from space to tab and rebooted all worked as expected.